# How to resolve: `pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot watch resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"`

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, bigdata, spark-submit

I want to use Kubernetes as resource manager for spark.

so I wanted to submit a jar far to spark cluster with  `spark-submit`:

```
./bin/spark-submit  \
    --master k8s://https://vm:6443 \
    --class com.example.WordCounter  \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=default  \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=private-docker-registery/spark/spark:3.2.1-3 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=default \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthToken=$TOKEN  \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.caCertFile=api.cert \
    java-word-count-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

for **service account**:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount spark
```

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding spark-role \
    --clusterrole=edit \
    --serviceaccount=default:default \
    --namespace=default
```

for **caCertFile** I used the `/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt` content.

and for **submission.oauthToken**:

`kubectl get  secret  spark-token-86tns -o yaml | grep token`

and use the token part.

but still doesn't work and I `pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot watch resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"` error

Comment: role is bind to `default`, while you are using `spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark `, it should be `default`

Comment: @Adiii , I have to edit my question. actually with `spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=default` again I got that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.kubernetes.authenticate.caCertFile` has to be `service account` cert

and also `spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthToken` has to be `service account` token.

both cert and token can be found in service account secret.

- be careful to decode `service account` cert and token (base64 -d).